Unable to map different ip address then hostname while accessing openproject
Unable to map different ip address then hostname while accessing openproject. Tried different methods including docker compose but still cannot map the ip address that i want to set instead of hostname.

relevance to Ubuntu? Please read [ask] then [edit] accordingly
